# Is there a progress bar feature for pytube?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytube

I want to add a progress bar to the youtube download feature. what modules do I need to represent this bar?

I tried importing tqdm and I created a default progress bar using a for loop over a range of 1000.
However, I don't know how I'll use tqdm with the YouTube class from pytube.

```
import pytube

video_url = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DF5if13xSoo"
youtube = pytube.YouTube(video_url)
video = youtube.streams.first()
video.download('/Users/hargunoberoi/Desktop/Python/YoutubeTest')
print("Download Complete!")
```

The code correctly downloads the youtube videos, but I just stare blankly at the command line waiting for the completion.
I want to know how much of the video is downloaded over time.

Comment: Read the docs. A cursory glance reveals a few 'progress' functions. There might be some parameters you should put in `pytube.Youtube(video_url)`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response @101arrowz
I see that it asks for a user-defined callback function. What does that mean? What could be a sample input?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We ask that you please [Read The Fine Manual](https://github.com/nficano/pytube/blob/63c39/pytube/cli.py#L133:L143):

> On download progress callback function.
>
> ```
> :param object stream:
>     An instance of :class:`Stream <Stream>` being downloaded.
> :param file_handle:
>     The file handle where the media is being written to.
> :type file_handle:
>     :py:class:`io.BufferedWriter`
> :param int bytes_remaining:
>     How many bytes have been downloaded.
> ```

The example call provided is:

```
def download(url, itag):
    ...
    yt = YouTube(url, on_progress_callback=on_progress)
```