# How to add tqdm to show progress bar when downloading you tube video with pytube?

Tags: python, youtube, python-3.6, tqdm, pytube

I am learning `pytube` to download Youtube video and tried `tqdm` on top of it to show progress bar but it shows various error and also I could not understand what is happening when I download video with `pytube` and showing progress bar which is the reason for me to not able to add `tqdm` in it.

The code I have written with `pytube` runs well, this is the code:

```py
from pytube import YouTube


url = str(input("Enter the video link: "))
yt = YouTube(url)
videos = yt.streams.filter(file_extension='mp4').all()

filename = yt.title


s = 1
for v in videos:
    print(str(s)+". "+str(v))
    s += 1

n = int(input("Enter the number of the video: "))
vid = videos[n-1]

vid.download("C:/Users/user/Downloads/")

print(yt.title,"\nHas been successfully downloaded")
```

I need `tqdm` to be added to the code to show a progress bar.

Comment: i wrote an answer that shows a tqdm progress bar for pytube downloads https://stackoverflow.com/a/69259177/5666087

Answer (score 10):

I don't know about `tqdm`, but there is a [progress bar feature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55882563/is-there-a-progress-bar-feature-for-pytube) for `pytube`.

I use it like this:

```py
from pytube.cli import on_progress
from pytube import YouTube as YT
...
yt = YT(video_url, on_progress_callback=on_progress)
yt.streams\
  .filter(file_extension='mp4')\
  .get_lowest_resolution()\
  .download(video_path)
```

Looks like this:

```
PSY - GANGNAM STYLE(강남스타일) MV.mp4
↳ |███████████████████████████████████████| 100.0%
```

Hope it helps!