# How to add "pytube" downloading info to tqdm Progress Bar?

Tags: python, tqdm, pytube

I am trying make a YouTube video downloader.
I want make a progress bar while downloading the YouTube video but I cant get any info (how many MB have been downloaded or how many video MB).
I don't know if this is possible with python or not. Here is my code so far:

```
import time , os
from pytube import YouTube
from tqdm import tqdm


al = str(input("C4ommand:"))


if al == "4":
    af = input("Link:")
    you = YouTube(af)

    try:
        os.mkdir("Download")
    except:
        pass

    time.sleep(2)
    time.sleep(1)
    res = you.streams.get_highest_resolution()
    a = res.download()
    with tqdm(total=100) as pbar:
        for i in range(10):
            time.sleep(0.5)
            pbar.update(10)
    print(af + "Link downloading....")
    b = open("\Download", "w")
    b.write(a)
    b.close()
    print("Downloaded")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access the progress of the download, you can use the `on_progress_callback` argument when creating a `YouTube` instance.

The [pytube quickstart](https://pytube.io/en/latest/user/quickstart.html) says the following:

> The `on_progress_callback` function will run whenever a chunk is downloaded from a video, and is called with three arguments: the stream, the data chunk, and the bytes remaining in the video. This could be used, for example, to display a progress bar.

```py
from pytube import Stream
from pytube import YouTube
from tqdm import tqdm


def progress_callback(stream: Stream, data_chunk: bytes, bytes_remaining: int) -> None:
    pbar.update(len(data_chunk))


url = "http://youtube.com/watch?v=2lAe1cqCOXo"
yt = YouTube(url, on_progress_callback=progress_callback)
stream = yt.streams.get_highest_resolution()
print(f"Downloading video to '{stream.default_filename}'")
pbar = tqdm(total=stream.filesize, unit="bytes")
path = stream.download()
pbar.close()
print(f"Saved video to {path}")
```

Sample output:

```
Downloading video to 'YouTube Rewind 2019 For the Record  YouTubeRewind.mp4'
100%|██████████████████████████████| 87993287/87993287 [00:17<00:00, 4976219.51bytes/s]
Saved video to /tmp/testing/YouTube Rewind 2019 For the Record  YouTubeRewind.mp4
```

---

Pytube has a built-in progress bar, but it does not use `tqdm`. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/a/60678355/5666087 for more information.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you want. I made it just now and it can be documented a bit better:

```py
from tqdm import tqdm
from pytube import Stream, YouTube

class TqdmForPyTube(tqdm):

    def on_progress(self, stream: Stream, chunk: bytes, bytes_remaining: int):
        """
        :param stream: pytube object.
        :param bytes chunk: segment of media file binary data,
            not yet written to disk.
        :param int bytes_remaining: the delta between the total file size
            in bytes and amount already downloaded.
        """
        self.total = stream.filesize
        bytes_downloaded = self.total - bytes_remaining
        return self.update(bytes_downloaded - self.n)
```

And to use it, as explain in the [tqdm documentation](https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm#hooks-and-callbacks):

```py
with TqdmForPyTube(unit='B', unit_scale=True, unit_divisor=1024, delay=2) as t:
    print('downloading video...')
    YouTube(video_url, on_progress_callback=t.on_progress).\
            streams.filter(...).download(output_path=output_path)
    print(video downloaded')
```

I used the `delay=2` argument to avoid printing the first null tqdm iteration in the case you want to print something in console before calling the `download` function, as in the line `print('downloading video...')`, but it's not needed otherwise.